# Importing video in kodi Movies Library using metatag title instead of filename

Tags: video, metadata, kodi, mkv

I am trying to make sense of the documentation for Kodi and Video Tagging. The documentation [states](http://kodi.wiki/view/Video_File_Tagging#Title):

> It seems that Kodi will not import a media file without a valid title
>   in the metadata tag. This makes it the most critical tag of all.
>
> Title also differs from Filename - I may have a file called
>   Blade_Runner_2049_(2017)Withalotofexcessinformation.mp4, But the title
>   value can simply be "Blade Runner 2049". Kodi will then display "Blade
>   Runner 2049).

So here is what I tried on my side (as a native French speaker). I like using my own file name convention, for instance: `2010 Moi, moche et méchant (Despicable Me).mkv`. To make the video easily imported in Video Library I tried a simple:

```
$ mkvpropedit "2010 Moi, moche et méchant (Despicable Me).mkv" --edit info --set title="Despicable Me"
```

However when I import a folder with this file in it, it continue to fail to recognize it. I need to manually fix the library entry ([Refresh option](http://kodi.wiki/view/Set_content_and_scan#Refreshing_the_library)).

So my questions:

1. What does the title metatag inside MP4 or MKV does actually ?
2. Is there a way to keep my own filename convention AND set enough metatag to get the file to be recognize properly (I am not a big fan of [NFO](http://kodi.wiki/view/NFO_files/movies)).

---

Update I also tried the following experiment:

```
$ mkvpropedit "Blade.mkv" --edit info --set title="Blade Runner 2049"
```

The movie with filename "Blade.mkv" is being recognized as 'Blade' instead of 'Blade Runner 2049'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starring at the source code long enough I figure the logic is here:

- https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/blob/17.6-Krypton/xbmc/video/VideoInfoScanner.cpp#L2099-L2115

The function `CVideoInfoScanner::FindVideo` only takes as input the filename as stored on disk. This leads to something like this in the debugger:

```
#0  VIDEO::CVideoInfoScanner::FindVideo (this=0x55757515fbf0, videoName="BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4", 
    scraper=std::shared_ptr (count 3, weak 1) 0x7f3b2801d780, url=..., progress=0x0) at VideoInfoScanner.cpp:2114
```

So this returns no result for the file eventhough the title was set nicely in the ISO Media, MP4 Base Media v1 [IS0 14496-12:2003] container

```
$ wget http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4
$ ffprobe -i BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4 2>&1| grep title
    title           : Big Buck Bunny
```

---

For comparison music is handled very differently since a whole set of tags are being read directly from the MP3 file itself, see:

- https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/blob/master/xbmc/music/tags/MusicInfoTag.h

---

Update

Because I believe this would a nice feature to have in future version, I did report an issue in Trac:

- https://trac.kodi.tv/ticket/17755

---

Update 2

I have prepared a pull request and it was accepted today:

- https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/pull/13519

Answer (score 2):

Best approach for you would probably be to add an nfo file with the same name and the info about the file in it.
See for reference: http://kodi.wiki/view/Nfo

Comment: I wanted something similar to [MusicBrainz picard](http://kodi.wiki/view/Music_tagging#MusicBrainz) but for MP4/MKV.

Comment: Yeah, that's not really how it works at the moment :/
The workflow would be to rename your files via something like filebot.
Or use nfo. I also thought you could change the parsing via advancedsettings.xml but I can't find any docs about that.

Comment: Make sense, but one need to pay attention to some weird character in filenames, I just shot myself in the foot using [':' (colon) in filename on NTFS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/114470/32896).